# For split String using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

date=2011-07-08 time=10:55:06 timezone="IST" device_name="CR1000i" device_id=C010600504-TYGJD3 deployment_mode="Route" log_id=031006209001 log_type="Anti Virus" log_component="FTP" log_subtype="Clean" status="Denied" priority=Critical fw_rule_id="" user_name="hemant" virus="codevirus"  FTP_URL="ftp.myftp.com" FTP_direction="download" filename="hemantresume.doc" file_size="550k" file_path="deepti/Shortcut to virus.lnk"  ftpcommand="RETR" src_ip=10.103.6.100 dst_ip=10.103.6.66 protocol="TCP" src_port=2458 dst_port=21 dstdomain="myftp.cpm" sent_bytes=162 recv_bytes=45 message="An FTP download of File resume.doc of size 550k  from server  ftp.myftp.com could not be completed as file was infected with virus codevirus"

Now i want the above string is split and give me the output based on the key-value pairs as below:

```
array[0]=date=2011-07-08

array[1]=time=10:55:06

array[2]=timezone="IST"

array[3]=device_name='CR1000i"

.......

.......
```

so please help me..thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you at least read the javadoc of the String class?

Comment: @asha - are there spaces in two tokens? i.e. btn date=2011-07-08 and time=10:55:06?

Comment: There can be spaces within quotes. That's the main difficulty. See the key `message`, for example. Then there may even be escaped quotes within the quotes, and the same old story begins.

Comment: split with paces if not surrounded by quotes

Comment: @JB Nizet..i have tried with this..but its not giving with numeric string..  String array[]=str.split("(\\w)(\")")

Comment: @Saurabh ..there is no space between the tokens..but you can see last token that is message ..that token value has spaces..so i can't even split with spaces..

Comment: @AshaKoshti Please check the code posted below. It has given me the desired result. Let me know if theres any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex (almost) like @Hlopik suggested, and then loop to find all matches:

```
String text = "dstdomain=\"myftp.cpm\" sent_bytes=162 recv_bytes=45 message=\"An FTP download of File resume.doc of size 550k from server ftp.myftp.com could not be completed as file was infected with virus codevirus\"";
String patternText = "\\w+=([^ \"]+|\"[^\"]*\")";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternText).matcher(text);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
```

If you really need the result as an `Array` for some reason you can use `matches.toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

just for an inspiration consider this regex: `\w*=(["][^"]*["]|[^ ]*)`
it matches any number of word (\w) characters, equals sign, and anything in the quotes or anything to the first space.. It matches your example, but surely there will be something that this regex will be too simple for :)

Comment: @Hlopik...as i am splitting with above regexe it gives me nothing..all as blank

Comment: It's not intended for split method, but for the matcher, as shown in beautiful @Keppil's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code. Please note that the code is in JAVA.

```
StringBuilder testt = new StringBuilder("date=2011-07-08 time=10:55:06 timezone=\"IST\" device_name=\"CR1000i\" device_id=C010600504-TYGJD3 deployment_mode=\"Route\" log_id=031006209001 log_type=\"Anti Virus\" log_component=\"FTP\" log_subtype=\"Clean\" status=\"Denied\" priority=Critical fw_rule_id=\"\" user_name=\"hemant\" virus=\"codevirus\" FTP_URL=\"ftp.myftp.com\" FTP_direction=\"download\" filename=\"hemantresume.doc\" file_size=\"550k\" file_path=\"deepti/Shortcut to virus.lnk\" ftpcommand=\"RETR\" src_ip=10.103.6.100 dst_ip=10.103.6.66 protocol=\"TCP\" src_port=2458 dst_port=21 dstdomain=\"myftp.cpm\" sent_bytes=162 recv_bytes=45 message=\"An FTP download of File resume.doc of size 550k from server ftp.myftp.com could not be completed as file was infected with virus codevirus\"");

Pattern varPattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z_]+=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher varMatcher = varPattern.matcher(testt);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

int startIndex = 0, endIndex=0;

boolean found=false;

while (varMatcher.find()) {

 endIndex = varMatcher.start();

 list.add(testt.substring(startIndex, endIndex));

 startIndex= varMatcher.start();

 found=true;

}

if(found){
 list.add(testt.substring(startIndex));
}

for(String s:list){
 System.out.println(s);
}
```